# Scaled container won't keep round shape (border-radius: 50%)?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a simple round-shaped container:

```
.foo {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

When I try to scale its size with:

```
.foo {
  -webkit-transform: scale(10,10);
          transform: scale(10,10);
}
```

It doesn't look that round anymore. Seems like its border-radius gets a value equal to the original border radius in pixels multiplied by the scale value.

https://jsfiddle.net/h70wsqrv/1/

[image]

Any ideas how to fix it?

UPDATE: Seems like the problem only occurs in Chrome. Firefox shows a perfect circle.

Comment: it looks ok in the fiddle. Could you describe better the issue

Comment: @Chris I've uploaded a screenshot. It doesn't look that round in Chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strange, but it works if you set width and height to `6px` or **any even number**.

Looks like radius is calculated wrong in Chrome when it is an odd number.

```css
.foo {
  margin: 100px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(15, 15);
  transform: scale(15, 15);
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Muhammet. This looks like a solution if the container size can be adjusted. I never though of this. Good job!

Comment: @Deka87 You are welcome. I don't know why they are not fixing this issue even if it was reported numerous times.